# How can I automatically press a button on the keyboard when it pops up? For example the letter "A"

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, keyboard

I want the letter "A" to get pressed on the keyboard without the user pressing it manually.
Or the "return" button.

Answer (score 1):

You should first think of the basic flow of how the app should work.

- Do you want the `A` to be pressed after x amount of time? Create a counter.
- Do you want it after x item appears? Use `.onAppear {}`
- Do you want it after x data refreshes? Use `.onChange..`

Think about the flow of the app then use the right tool to trigger it.